# laravel 5.2 sqlite connection error

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

I have this situation in laravel 5.2 where if I do this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

in the `.env` file I get **this:**

> InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34:
>       Database (database/database.sqlite) does not exist.

on trying to manipulate the `laravel` error rendering system with this code from a **controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class SampleController extends Controller
{
    public function findUser()
    {
       $user = User::firstOrFail();

       return $user->toArray();
    }
}
```

And this goes well with `php artisan migrate` command, but to get the `controller` code to render the error as expected I have to do this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=../database/database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

To fix the problem so I get both `php artisan migrate` and `SampleController` to work I have put this in the `config/database.php` file:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Why is the `default` means to access `sqlite` as given on the [laravel website](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database) not working. Is it a bug I should be aware of?

Comment: The `config.php` file is normally expected to contain `'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),` in it's `'sqlite'` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal configuration in the `config.php` file is expected to be

```
'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

Furthermore, the appropriate way to mention the `DB_DATABASE` in the `.env` file is to specify the absolute file name, such as `/var/www/laravel/database/database.sqlite` not the relative location.

For example, in `Windows`

```
DB_DATABASE=C:\wamp\www\laravel\database\database.sqlite
```

And this is what is mentioned in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#introduction)

```
DB_DATABASE=/absolute/path/to/database.sqlite
```